# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress HTTP to HTTPS redirect via 301 instead of 308?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

We are running a couple of k8s clusters on Azure AKS.
The service (ghost blog) is behind the Nginx ingress and secured with a cert from Letsencrypt.  All of that works fine but the redirect behavior is what I am having trouble with.

> The Ingress correctly re-directs from http://whatever.com to
> https://whatever.com — the issue is that it does so using a 308
> redirect which strips all post/page Meta anytime a user shares a
> page from the site.

The issue results in users who share any page of the site on most social properties receiving a 'Preview Link' — where the title of the page and the page meta preview do not work and are instead replaced with '308 Permanent Redirect' text — which looks like this:

[image]

From the [ingress-nginx docs over here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect) I can see that this is the intended behavior (ie. 308 redirect) what I believe is not intended is the interaction with social sharing services when those services attempt to create a page preview.

While the issue would be solved by Facebook (or twitter, etc etc) pointing direct to the https site by default, I currently have no way to force those sites to look to https for the content that will be used to create the previews.

### Setting Permanent Re-Direct Code

I can also see that it looks like I should be able to set the redirect code to whatever I want it to be (I believe a 301 redirect will allow Facebook et al. to correctly pull post/page snippet meta), [docs on that found here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#permanent-redirect-code).

The problem is that when I add the redirect-code annotation as specified:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect-code: "301"
```

I still get a 308 re-direct on my resources despite being able to see (from my kubectl proxy) that the redirect-code annotation correctly applied. For reference, my full list of annotations on my Ingress looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ghost-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect-code: "301"
```

> To reiterate — my question is; what is the correct way to force a redirect to https via a custom error code (in my case 301)?

Comment: What makes you think that you need a 301, are you pretty certain?

Comment: @rico I am certain that 308 results in dramatically suboptimal results for any site that receives much if it's traffic from social sharing.  Basically the link (when shared socially or via text) results in that service attempting to obtain a snippet of meta to construct a preview - the 308 redirect does work if the link is clicked but the preview looks like garbage and shows the title of the page as '308 redirect' (literally).  Most users don't know what this is and therefore won't click.  Of course I can personally just share the https link but I can't force my users to do the same.

Comment: ... looks bad in the preview ran out of characters : )

Comment: Added an answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is the TLS redirect shadows the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect-code` annotation.

You can actually change the `ConfigMap` for your `nginx-configuration` so that the default redirect is 301. That's the configuration your nginx ingress controller uses for nginx itself. The `ConfigMap` looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  use-proxy-protocol: "true"
  http-redirect-code: "301"
```

You can find more about the `ConfigMap` options [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/6393ca6aafe73d6f04cd2e1181cdd102e45fe75d/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md). Note that if you change the `ConfigMap` you'll have to restart your `nginx-ingress-controller` pod.

You can also shell into the `nginx-ingress-controller` pod and see the actual nginx  configs that the controller creates:

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx bash
www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx:/etc/nginx$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Will give this a shot in the A.M. @Rico.  I also added a screen shot to my original question to clarify exactly what the issue is and the visual result caused by the 308 redirect behavior (from a user perspective).  

I think that probably there are a lot of instances of this issue out there in the wild but because MOST of the time people are sharing the full link (with HTTPS) it goes un-noticed.

Comment: Just tried the above ConfigMap solution.  Just a heads up that you will need quotes around the "301" code.  No idea if this will solve the overall problem but this DOES force nGinx Ingress to use a 301 code — whether facebook, twiiter and the other social properties will now properly 'find' / create the preview meta is yet to be clear — I will post back with any additional thoughts on the process.

Comment: Thanks, added the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> These directions are for Azure AKS users but the solution for this solution for facebook / social property preview links showing as 308 permanent redirect will probably work on any cloud provider (though it has not been tested) — you would just need to change the way you login / get your credentials etc.

Thanks to Rico for the solution!  Since this is only tested with Facebook you may or may not want to go the ConfigMap application route (which Rico mentions above) this walks through manually editing the ConfigMap as opposed to using `kubectl apply -f` to apply one saved locally.

1. Pickup AZ Credentials for your cluser (`az login`)
2. Assume the role for your cluster: `az aks get-credentials --resource-group yourGroup --name your-cluster`
3. Browse your Cluster: `az aks browse --resource-group yourGroup --name your-cluster`
4. Navigate to the namespace containing your Ingress nGinx containers (not the backend services — although they could be in the same NS).
5. On the left hand side navigation menu (just above settings) find the 'ConfigMaps' tab and click it.
6. Edit the 'Data' element of the YAML and add the following line (note the quotes around both the name and number in the key/value):

   `"data": {
     "some-other-setting-here": "false",
     "http-redirect-code": "301"
   }`

   You will need a comma after each key/value line except the last.
7. Restart your nginx-controller POD by deleting it *make SURE* you don't delete the deployment like I did.
8. If you want to be productive you can upgrade your nginx install (from helm) which will restart / re-create the container in the process by using:
   `helm upgrade ngx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress`
   Where ngx-ingress is the name of your helm install.  Also note that using the '--reuse-values' flag will cause your upgrade to fail (re: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4337)
9. If you don't know the name you used for nginx when you installed it from Helm originally you can use `helm list` to find it.
10. Finally to test and make sure your Re-Directs are using the correct ConfigMap code, curl your http site with:
    `curl myhttpdomain.com`
    You should receive something like this:

```

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.15.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

```

One important thing to note here is that if you are making the change to a 301 re-direct to try to fix the preview link for facebook or one of the other social media properties (twitter etc etc) then in all likelihood this will not fix any link to any page / post that you have already linked to — at least not right away.

The social properties all use intense caching to limit their resource usage but you can check to see if the above fixes your preview link issue by linking to a NEW page / post that you have not previously referenced.

### Be Aware of Implications for 'POST'

So the major reason that nginx-ingress uses a code 308 is because it keeps the 'body' / payload intact in cases where you are sending a POST request (as opposed to a normal GET request link you do with a browser etc).

For me this wasn't a concern but if you are for whatever reason posting to the http address and expecting that to be re-directed seamlessly that will probably not work — after you swap to the 301 redirect discussed in post that is.

HOWEVER if you are not expecting a seamless redirect when sending POST requests (I think most people probably are not, I know I am not) then I think this is the best way to fix the Facebook 308 Permanent redirect behavior.